# Three.js animation issues, it doesn't move

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'd appreciate if someone who knows three.js could help me fix my code so it will make a sphere move.  I've looked at every example I can find where they use json data, but they're all pretty complex.  Thanks!

My code snippets:

```
function animate(t) {
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    // renderer automatically clears unless autoClear = false
    //window.requestAnimationFrame(animate, renderer.domElement);
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    render();
}

function render(){
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}

function updateSpheres(pos1, pos2){
  var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 10, 10, 10 );
  var violetMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x6259CA , transparent: true, opacity: 0.5 } );
  sphereAnimate = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, violetMaterial)
  scene.add(sphereAnimate);
  var animationData = {
          "name"      : "Action",
          "fps"       : 3,
          "length"    : 2.0,
          "hierarchy" : [
            {
              "parent" : -1, //root
              "keys"   : [
                {
                  "time":0,
                  "pos" :[0,0,0],
                  "rot" :[0,0,0],
                  "scl" :[1,1,1]
                },
                {
                  "time":1.0,
                  "pos" :[3,0,3],
                   "rot" :[0,0,0],
                  "scl" :[1,1,1]
                },
                {
                  "time":2.0,
                  "pos" :[0,60,0],
                  "rot" :[0,0,0],
                  "scl" :[1,1,1]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        };
  console.log(geometry);
  var sphereMeshAnimation = new THREE.Animation( sphereAnimate, animationData );
  //ensureLoop( animationData );

  sphereMeshAnimation.play();
  //sphereMeshAnimation.update(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not call anything to update your animation in the animate function.

Should do it by `THREE.AnimationHandler.update( delta );` like in here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/misc_animation_keys.html#L159

Animations apparently register automagically to the handler so you already seem to have that part correctly: the creation of THREE.Animation and calling .play() on it .. just need to add that handler updating.